# Enable logging in postgresql using docker-compose

Tags: postgresql, docker, logging, docker-compose

I am using Postgres as a service in my docker-compose file. I want logging to log file to be enabled when I do `docker-compose up`. One way to enable logging is by editing `postgres.conf` file but it's not useful in this case. One other way is to do something like this

`docker run --name postgresql -itd --restart always sameersbn/postgresql:10-2 -c logging_collector=on`

but this isn't useful too cause I am not starting it from an image but as a docker-compose service. Any idea how I can start the docker-compose up with logging enabled in Postgres???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Just like you command with docker run:

```
docker run --name postgresql -itd --restart always sameersbn/postgresql:10-2 -c logging_collector=on
```

that you add the `-c logging_collector=on` arguments for the `ENTRYPOINT ["/sbin/entrypoint.sh"]` to enable logging. ([Dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/r/sameersbn/postgresql/dockerfile)).

- In **docker-compose.yml** file, use `command:` like this:

```yaml
version: "3.7"
services:
  database:
    image: sameersbn/postgresql:10-2
    command: "-c logging_collector=on"

# ......
```

When Postgresql container run, it will run command: `/sbin/entrypoint.sh -c logging_collector=on`.

Comment: For more info:
https://goinbigdata.com/docker-run-vs-cmd-vs-entrypoint/
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#command

Comment: how to specify log levels ?

Answer (score 6):

Here is the docker-compose to run the command `-c` in compose

```
          version: '3.6'
          services:
            postgresql:
              image: postgres:11.5
              container_name: platops_postgres
              volumes: ['platops-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/', 'postgress-logs:/var/log/postgresql/']
              command: ["postgres", "-c", "logging_collector=on", "-c", "log_directory=/logs", "-c", "log_filename=postgresql.log", "-c", "log_statement=all"]
              environment:
                - POSTGRES_USER=postgresql
                - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgresql
              ports: ['5432:5432']
          volumes:
            platops-data: {}
              # uncomment and set the path of the folder to maintain persistancy
              # data-postgresql:
              # driver: local
              # driver_opts:
              #   o: bind
              #   type: none
              #   device: /path/of/db/postgres/data/
            postgress-logs: {}
              # uncomment and set the path of the folder to maintain persistancy
              # data-postgresql:
              # driver: local
              # driver_opts:
              #   o: bind
              #   type: none
              #   device: /path/of/db/postgres/logs/
```

For more information, you can check with the containers/postgress

Comment: I had to put `["postgres", "-c", "logging_collector=on", "-c", "log_directory=/logs", "-c", "log_filename=postgresql.log", "-c", "log_statement=all"]` in brackets on docker-compose yaml 3.6 version